# rank of an even-diagonal integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If $A$ is a  $(2n+1)\times(2n+1)$ matrix, all of its entries integer, whose diagonal elements are even, and all the other elements odd, is the minimum of the rank of $A$ equal to $2n$ ?

And I'm not sure whether sending to $mod 2$ preserves the rank

Comment: sending to mod 2 doesn't preserve the rank, it only preserves the odd determinant (if det(A) is odd, it will remain odd after sending all elements to mod 2 and vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* It suffices to prove that the leading $2n\times2n$ principal minor is nonzero, but this is evident in modulo 2 arithmetic.

Comment: how can I see it is evident?

Comment: @sacch The submatrix is (in modulo 2 arithmetic) $I_{2n}+\mathbf1\mathbf1^T$, where $\mathbf1$ is the vector with all entries equal to $1$. Can you evaluate its determinant?

Comment: using Sylvester's equality! thanks